# Changing time format in template is raising exception

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I can't figure out why `Django` returns `Exception` when I try to set time format in template.

This is a column in `Django-tables2` table.

```
time_arrival = tables.TemplateColumn('{{record.time_arrival|time: "H:i"}}',verbose_name=u'Čas príchodu')
```

The `time_arrival` is an attribute of `Reservation` model which is a `record` in this table. When there is just `{{ record.time_arrival }}` it shows time in this format: `1 p.m.` but I want to show `13:00` for example so I have to change the format.

This exception is being raised:

```
Exception Value: Could not parse the remainder: ': "H:i"' from 'record.time_arrival|time: "H:i"'
```

This is a `time_arrival` attribute in `Reservation` model:

```
time_arrival = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=u'Čas príletu')
```

Do you know where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space between `time:` and `"H:i"`

```
'{{record.time_arrival|time:"H:i"}}'
```

Comment: OMG...what to say.. I've tried multiple things except this... thank you :)